# Custom loss function in keras returns nan loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

Following is my custom loss function in keras.
  Both `y_true` and `y_pred` have shape `(256,384,3)`.

```
def myloss(y_true,y_pred):
    diff = y_pred - y_true
    diff = diff[96:160 , 144:240]
    return K.mean(K.square(diff), axis=-1)
```

Here I'm slicing a portion of the difference and finding the `mean_square_loss` for that. However, this function is returning `nan` as the loss. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure `y_pred` does not have `nan`? Sometimes the model gradients could be `nan` and mess up everything...

Comment: @Richard_wth  When I'm using the standard keras `mean_squared_error` as the loss, it's not giving me `nan`s. So I don't think the problem is with `y_pred`

Comment: Your code seems legit to me...Would `diff = diff[0:256, 0:384]` also give `nan`?